# Abstract class in C# without any abstract method

Tags: c#, .net

Folks

I am surprised to see my code working, that I dont have any abstract method in abstract class. But as per rules we should have atleast one abstract method right ? :S

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you don't need an abstract method in an abstract class.

The restrictions are:

- If a class has an abstract method, property, index, or event then the class must also be abstract.
- You can't instantiate an abstract class.

There is no requirement that abstract classes must have abstract methods.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is entirely valid. Indeed, every `static` class in C# is actually an abstract *and sealed* class in .NET. (You can't declare an abstract class to be sealed with C# source code though.)

The C# 4 spec explicitly calls this out, in section 10.1.1.1 (abstract classes):

> An abstract class is permitted (but not required) to contain abstract members.

It's certainly *rare* to have an abstract class with no abstract members, but it's not unheard of. (Don't forget that it's not just methods that can be abstract - you can have abstract events and properties, too.)

Comment: I never tried abstract sealed class ;) but can I ask you why they prevent this? (I didn't ask it as new Q because I didn't search around it, If is possible for you with short hint or link).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I think the whole purpose of abstract class is that it should serve as base class for other child classes.... Jon am I giving a good reason ? Please correct me if not..... thank you.... I am new and excited to learn :)

Comment: @Divine: Yes, that makes sense. The point of a static class being both abstract and sealed is to utterly prevent instantiation.

Comment: @JonSkeet Cool thank you. So your statement means that, abstract class can be instantiated through derived class like Derived d = new Base(); where Base is abstract. But with Static, no instance at all. Hope I have my understanding level correct to this point...

Comment: Yes abstract class is for instantiation, may be I should why static classes are abstract.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: To prevent you from trying to instantiate them.

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN - abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5) (Emphasis added):

> An abstract class **may** contain abstract methods and accessors.

Your abstract class can contain nothing but non-abstract methods, or it could be am empty class if you want.  It gives you a base class that cannot be instantiated, which could be useful for plymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need abstract methods to have an abstract class. Sometimes it's useful to just restrict a class from being instantiated, and designate it as a base to some inheritance hierarchy. All the methods can be defined in an abstract class.